# Count consecutive pairs of same elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array `arr[]`, the task is to return `true` if there is **5 or more** consecutive `1` in the array:

```
let arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1] // returns false => 4 consecutive 1
let arr = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0] // returns true => 5 consecutive 1
```

Note: The array only contains 0 and 1

Comment: *the task is to*? The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

You could check it with a counter.

```js
const check5 = array => array.some((c => v => !(v ? ++c : (c = -5)))(-5));

console.log(check5([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
console.log(check5([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a for loop, iterating every entry of the array, incrementing a counter if it's 1 and resetting it if it's a 0

```js
let arr1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1] // returns false => 4 consecutive 1
let arr2 = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0] // returns true => 5 consecutive 1
let arr3 = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1] // returns true => 5 consecutive 1

function hasConsecutiveOnes(arr) {
  let counter = 0;
  
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== 1) {
      counter = 0;
    } else if (arr[i] === 1) {
      if(counter + 1 === 5) {
       return true
      }
      counter++
    } else {
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
  
  return false
  
}

console.log(hasConsecutiveOnes(arr1))
console.log(hasConsecutiveOnes(arr2))
console.log(hasConsecutiveOnes(arr3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const fiveOnes = (arr) => {
  let oneCount = 0;
  for(let a of arr){
    if(a===0){
      oneCount = 0;
    }
    else{
      oneCount++;
      if(oneCount>=5) break;
    }
  }

  return (oneCount >= 5);
}
```

Edit: Increment the counter every time you get a '1' and reset the counter back to 0 when ever you get a '0' in the array. When the total count of consecutive '1's equals 5 exit the loop to save time and return the result.

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: @Lemon Kazi, I agree. Thanks for the comment.